# Why does this strange symbol appear on each line in my Linux boot log?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, logging, symbols

```
[154G
```

Each line of my boot.log file in Ubuntu has an escape symbol that is two zeros on a top row and 1b on a bottom row surrounded by a one line frame, then the text `154G` then the expected `[ ok ]` or `[ failed ]`.

Why is the boxed symbol written on each line and what does it mean?

Boot.log Screen shot:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This question isn't off-topic, so please don't vote to close as such. I think this question is a bit unclear, though. An image would be very useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are peeking into data that should be sent to a device that understands ANSI sequences.

`1B` is the HEX code for "ESC", (escape, character 27 in the ASCII table. The Unicode equivalent is `u001B`, which might be why it is displayed in that manner.
`[` is part of the introduction of ANSI sequences, when paired with ESC.
`154` is a parameter, and `G` tells the function to run with that parameter.

Type `od -t x1z boot.log | less` to see the contents in hex and text formats, side by side.

Assuming that your terminal understands the sequence:
`head -n 30 boot.log` should display the text formatted in the manner it was intended to be seen.